# Avoiding MySQL Deadlocks in a multithreaded Spring app

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, spring

The scenario is simple.
I have a somehow large MySQL db containing two tables:

```
-- Table 1
id (primary key) | some other columns without constraints
-----------------+--------------------------------------
       1         |       foo
       2         |       bar
       3         |       foobar
      ...        |       ...

-- Table 2
id_src | id_trg | some other columns without constraints
-------+--------+---------------------------------------
   1   |   2    |    ...
   1   |   3    |    ...
   2   |   1    |    ...
   2   |   3    |    ...
   2   |   5    |    ...
   ...
```

- On table1 only `id` is a primary key. This table contains about 12M entries.
- On table2 `id_src` and `id_trg` are both primary keys and both have foreign key constraints on table1's `id` and they also have the option `DELETE ON CASCADE` enabled. This table contains about 110M entries.

Ok, now what I'm doing is only to create a list of `id`s that I want to remove from table 1 and then I'm executing a simple `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (<the list of ids>);`

The latter process is as you may have guessed would delete the corresponding id from table2 as well. So far so good, but the **problem** is that when I run this on a multi-threaded env and I get many `Deadlocks`!

**A few notes:**

- There is no other process running at the same time nor will be (for the time being)
- I want this to be fast! I have about 24 threads (if this does make any difference in the answer)
- I have already tried almost all of transaction isolation levels (except the TRANSACTION_NONE) [Java sql connection transaction isolation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)
- Ordering/sorting the id's I think would not help!
- I have already tried `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but a simple `DELETE` would take up to 30secs! (so there is no use of using it) :

  ```
  DELETE FROM table1 
  WHERE id IN ( 
      SELECT id FROM (
          SELECT * FROM table1 
          WHERE id='some_id' 
          FOR UPDATE) AS x);
  ```

How can I fix this?

I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**

1. Using InnoDB engine
2. On a single thread this process would take a dozen hours even maybe a whole day, but I'm aiming for a few hours!
3. I'm already using a connection pool manager: `java.util.concurrent`
4. For explanation on double nested `SELECT`s please refer to [MySQL can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/831164/MySQL-can-t-specify-target-table-for-update-in-FRO)
5. The list that is to be deleted from DB, may contain a couple of million entries in total which is divided into chunks of 200
6. The `FOR UPDATE` clause is that I've heard that it locks a single row instead of locking the whole table
7. The app uses Spring's batchUpdate(String sqlQuery) method, thus the transactions are managed automatically
8. All ids have index enabled and the ids are unique 50 chars max!
9. `DELETE ON CASCADE` on `id_src` and `id_trg` (each separately) would mean that every delete on table1 `id=x` would lead to deletes on table2 `id_src=x` and `id_trg=x`
10. Some code as requested:

    ```
    public void write(List data){
        try{
            Arraylist idsToDelete = getIdsToDelete();
            String query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ("+ idsToDelete + " )";
            mysqlJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(query);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.error(e);
           }
    }
    ```

and `myJdbcTemplate` is just an abstract class that extends `JdbcDaoSupport`.

Comment: Use a connection pooler like BoneCP, C3P0 or DBCP to manage your connections.

Comment: Why do you need several threads?

Comment: Why do you have 2 nested selects?

Comment: I think @Soana has a point can you use the query like DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE id IN ( 
        SELECT id FROM table1 
        WHERE id IN (<a list of ids>) 
        FOR UPDATE);

Comment: @shazin Already tried that, I get the following error: `“Error Code: 1093 You can’t specify target table ‘my_table’ for update in FROM clause”`

Comment: I should not take that long. is the id indexed? Why not get the id one by one from the list of id and store them in a list and then delete the regs?

Comment: @PbxMan Sorry my bad, I updated the query, the actual query is this! which takes up to 30secs to delete just one row on an indexed column `id`

Comment: From my reading, it seems that the reason you are using multiple threads is solely to improve the performance of the delete. I would not expect multithreading to speed up the process of deleting records from a database. There are certain realities about how the database has to read and write to disk here, and having more resources *competing* for the disk and incurring additional overhead of going back and forth to the disk multiple times is not likely to result in a speed up. If I've understood correctly, then I would call this an XY problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have already tried the app in other conditions as well. In other words, the same app could run on 24 threads and delete entries faster than a single thread.

Comment: Then you should investigate why the performance is so bad using a single query, and you may well find an alternative answer for speeding it up. I'm still convinced this is an XY problem and that an alternative solution would work better. @PbxMan Is absolutely correct asking whether this table is indexed at all. Indexes are usually the first thing to consider when thinking about performance.

Comment: Why do you need `FOR UPDATE` in your `SELECT`? That's a cross-transactional locking mechanism. What happens for a single, non-concurrent query if you remove it? Also, I notice your `id` column is a string. How long are those strings? Have you considered using a surrogate key instead of a string ID?

Comment: You've "heard" what exactly about it? I can't see *any* compelling reason to lock out other transactions from reading rows that *haven't been deleted yet*. That's the kind of problem transactions protect you from to begin with; until there's a `COMMIT`, those rows are available to any other transaction just fine.

Comment: You might need to consider the possibility that deleting a few million rows is just going to take some time and that there may be no way around that.

Comment: I cannot understand where are the transactions. What I mean is what is the unit of work, that will be rollbacked if something goes wrong : the full list of all id or every single id from table 1 ? And what indexes do you have on both table ? You say you have a DELETE ON CASCADE ; does it mean that when you delete a row from table 1 rows from table 2 are also deleted and which rows, both id_src = table1.id **and** id.trg = table1 .id ?

Comment: A down vote with an explanation would be constructive.

Comment: This is a XY problem. You only say in last edit that *The app uses Spring Batch*, but without telling how, nor how you try to delete. Deleting 200 records including child records with less than 100 childs per record on a correctly indexed database should only take seconds with a batch statement `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = ?` repeated 200 times, **independently of table size**.

Comment: @SergeBallesta There must have been a confusion because there have been many questions and edits which may finally lead this question to an off-topic or a non-constructive one. But the problem is as I explained it: I create a simple arraylist of the IDs that I want to be removed and then using the method `batchUpdate(sqlQuery)` from Spring, this simple query is executed: `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (<the list of ids>);`. Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: `batchUpdate(sqlQuery)` from Spring is **not** Spring Batch ... but it is now much more clear :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry about that, thanks, fixed that in the question :)

Comment: You should show some code so that we can see how you actually access the database.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your first simple delete query in which you are passing ids, should not create problem if you are passing ids till a limit like 1000 (total no of rows in child table also should be near about but not to many like 10,000 etc.), but if you are passing like 50,000 or more then it can create locking issue.

To avoid deadlock, you can follow below approach to take care this issue (assuming bulk deletion will not be part of production system)-

Step1: Fetch all ids by select query and keep in cursor.

Step2: now delete these ids stored in cursor in a stored procedure one by one.

Note: To check why deletion is acquiring locks we have to check several things like how many ids you are passing, what is transaction level set at DB level, what is your Mysql configuration setting in my.cnf etc...

Comment: problem with your primary key as it is char type even 50, you should make this field as unique as per your requirement and create a new int or bigint column as primary key, then delete based on primary key...if you are able to change schema...Also share your prepared delete query with few ids exactly you are executing on server....

Answer (score 3):

It may be dangereous to delete many (> 10000) parent records each having child records deleted by cascade, because the most records you delete in a single time, the most chances of lock conflict leading to deadlock or rollback.

If it is acceptable (meaning you can make a direct JDBC connection to the database) you should (no threading involved here) :

- compute the list of ids to delete
- delete them by batches (between 10 and 100 a priori) committing every 100 or 1000 records

As the heavier job should be on database part, I hardly doubt that threading will help here. If you want to try it, I would recommend :

- one single thread (with a dedicated database connection) computing the list of ids to delete and alimenting a synchronized queue with them
- a small number of threads (4 maybe 8), each with its own database connection that :

  - use a prepared `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = ?` in batches
  - take ids from the queue and prepare the batches
  - send a batch to the database every 10 or 100 records
  - do a commit every 10 or 100 batches

I cannot imagine that the whole process could take more than several minutes.

After some other readings, it looks like I was used to old systems and that my numbers are really conservative.

Comment: Changing the app totaly at the moment is not an option. So staying with Spring, I've already tried `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = ?` which is a lot slower and thus uses more resources than using `id IN ()`. In your opinion raising the chunk size would it help accelerate the process? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I did, it might not actually avoid having Deadlocks but was my only option at time being.

This solution is actually a way of **handling** MySQL Deadlocks using Spring.

Catch and retry Deadlocks:

```
public void write(List data){
    try{
        Arraylist idsToDelete = getIdsToDelete();
        String query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ("+ idsToDelete + " )";
        try {
             mysqlJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(query);
        } catch (org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException e) {
             LOG.info("Caught DEADLOCK : " + e);
             retryDeadlock(query); // Retry them!
        }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           LOG.error(e);
       }
}

public void retryDeadlock(final String[] sqlQuery) {
    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    TimeoutRetryPolicy policy = new TimeoutRetryPolicy();
    policy.setTimeout(30000L);
    template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    try {
        template.execute(new RetryCallback<int[]>() {

            public int[] doWithRetry(RetryContext context) {
                LOG.info("Retrying DEADLOCK " + context);
                return mysqlJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sqlQuery);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use Spring's multiple *step* mechanism.
So that the DELETE queries are split into 3 and thus by starting the first step by deleting the blocking column and other steps delete the two other columns respectively.

```
Step1: Delete id_trg from child table;
Step2: Delete id_src from child table;
Step3: Delete id from parent table;
```

Of course the last two steps could be merged into 1, but in that case two distinct ItemsWriters would be needed!